# How can i recieve additional data from custom auth0 webhook?

Tags: node.js, auth0

Ok so this is the login flow of the user:

User visits /login

```
const config = {
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
    secret: env.auth_secret,
    baseURL: env.auth_base_url,
    clientID: env.auth_client_id,
    issuerBaseURL: 'url',

};

app.use(auth(config));
```

User logs in or signs up through the login prompt created by auth0.
When login is successfull, a webhook from auth0 sends event and secret data to /user/verified

```
const axios = require("axios");
const URL = 'https://0bg7-34-200-103-108.ngrok-free.app/user/verified';
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  
  try {
    await axios.post(URL, {data: event, secret: event.secrets.webhook_secret});
    
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
};
```

In my backend i check if the user is verified or not

Question:

Lets say the user enters /login/someData/

How could i access "someData" in my /user/verfied endpoint?

I am using nodejs as my backend.